# Low latency distributed in memory hash map (counts map)

Tags: algorithm, redis, key-value-store

I am trying to build a service which could store a few (<=100) counts maps where each counts map could store ~1 Billion unique keys and the counts would never exceed MAX_INT. The operations I would be running on each of the counts map would be:

- Numerous increment operations (Average of 10 increments per key) -
  The increment operations could be triggered from a bunch (~10) of
  different nodes.
- A single operation at the end to get all key/values
  (preferably streamed) of a given hash map after all the increments
  are done. At this point, we would essentially delete the counts map
  after reading all the keys. Also we are guaranteed that their would
  be no writes once we start reading the key/value counts

The most essential requirement is that each increment operation should have super low latency. Durability is not a concern but correctness is quintessential.

I have looked into Redis and Hazelcast. Looking for opinions from people with experience using technologies suited for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Redis Hash](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes) for each count map, and use [HINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/hincrby) to do the increments, and [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/hscan) or [HGETALL](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall) to obtain the key/values.

You'll need to implement a mechanism to guarantee the "no writes once start reading", take a look at [Redis Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) mechanism for example.

Comment: How does Redis scale for the kind of scale I am looking for?

Comment: See how [Twitter does it](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/9/8/how-twitter-uses-redis-to-scale-105tb-ram-39mm-qps-10000-ins.html)

Comment: "The hometime line can be largish, what is reasonable for a viewer to read in one set. Maybe 3000 entries, for example. Which means for performance reasons accessing the databases should be avoided." Like I said above, once all the key/value have been updated, there would be 1 query to get all the key/values. Would this create performance concerns?